# Is there a way to programmatically click links, input info into login forms, etc in Objective-C? (like Mechanize does)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there anything similar to Mechanize for Objective-C? I want to enter info into a search bar, select a link, and then extract some information from the webpage

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm new to Objective-c and programming...

Answer (score 0):

You can either [run JavaScript code in the context of your WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) or [interact with its DOM yourself](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/mainFrameDocument).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript into the page to do what you want with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. For example to simulate a click, inject:

```
getElementById('the_button').click();
```